# How to display pop up image when click point in OpenLayers web map

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wms, image, getfeatureinfo

I have basic WMS web map showing parcels and points layers which representing buildings of parcel. Then I want to add building images for each and every point. Then when a user clicks on a point image should appear as a pop up window.

I am using  OpenLayers 2.10 Beginner's Guide book and can't find any method to do the above thing.

Is this possible with OpenLayers? If so please give me some advise or some links to help me.

All layer are in WMS form and I am using GeoServer and Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a getfeatureinfo request and then display the result in a popup. The basics of this are shown in [this example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html). Once you have this working with your data you will want to format the information returned by the getfeatureinfo request so that it displays the image GeoServer provides a templating language that will allow you to do this - see this [tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/freemarker.html#tutorial-freemarkertemplate) for more details and an [example](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html).